# What do I need to be concerned with when forking a process and reading files?

Tags: python, fork

I am fairly new to forking and I have over 10,000 files stored in a folder that I am reading by doing the following:

```
#loop over all xFiles in a list of files
try:
    f = open(xFile, 'r', encoding="utf8")
    #search through file for terms
    #do other stuff
except:
    #Someone removed the file cannot be found.
    print("\tFile no longer exists:", xFile)
 f.close()
```

Because my script takes around 45 minutes to run, and due to the nature of the project I am working on, it is possible and very common that a file in the list of files I am searching through sometimes are moved or deleted. That is why my reading is wrapped in a try statement.

Where the following comment "search through file for terms" is inserted I am running an algorithm over thousands of patterns. I wish to fork my process before the loop so that I have two processes with different sets of patterns (different sizes) searching (or reading) through the same list of files.

Some of my concerns:

1. If one process is reading a file and it's child process tries to read that file, the except will execute and the search algorithm will never execute for that particular file.
2. I won't be able to read the same file simultaneously with both processes.

So here is my question after providing the context, What do I need to be concerned with when forking a process and reading the same files between both processes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming a *nix type system.

When you fork a process the file descriptors are accessible by both. That means the single kernel data is being accessed by two processes. This is bad in your situation. You would want to open the files *after* the fork so each process had its own access (and offset into) the file.

You would want to open a file descriptor *before* forking typically when the child process is changing permissions, such as a web server. The parent process opens a socket on port 80 as the root user, but then forks a child process that will listen on the file descriptor that points to the open port 80. The child process can then drop to a normal user (not root) and continue accepting new connections.

Hope that helps!